# how to highlight the radio buttons one after the other in following code

Tags: python, tkinter

How to highlight the radio buttons one after the other in following code?

The following code is in working condition but we are not able to highlight button automatically (scanning):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice, i.e. a

languages = [
    ("a",1),
    ("b",2),
    ("c",3),
    ("d",4),
    ("e",5)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print(v.get())

tk.Label(root, 
         text="""Choose your favourite 
programming language:""",
         justify = tk.LEFT,
         padx = 36).pack()

for val, language in enumerate(languages):
    tk.Radiobutton(root, 
                  text=language,
                  padx = 20, 
                  variable=v, 
                  command=ShowChoice,
                  value=val).pack(anchor=tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: *"highlight button automatically (scanning)"*: It's not clear what you want to do? Please [edit] your Question and explain in detail, even PSEYDOCODE, what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

store each of your radio buttons into a list ... change it to

```
radios = []
r_config = {'padx':20, 'variable':v, 'command':ShowChoice}
for val, language in enumerate(languages):
    radios.append(tk.Radiobutton(root,  text=language,     
                  value=val,**r_config))
    radios[-1].pack(anchor=tk.W)
```

then you can reference their config later in an update method

```
selected = -1
def color_tick():
    global selected # ... ewww
    radios[selected].config(bg=root.cget('bg'))
    selected = (selected+1)%len(radios)
    radios[selected].config(bg="yellow")
    # schedule a new call in 1 second
    root.after(1000,color_tick)

color_tick() # start the ticks
root.mainloop()
```